# How to apply python iloc on snakemake input file?

Tags: python, pandas, function, indexing, snakemake

More in detail:
I would like to choose one specific column based on a header value from snakemake rule input file and then select this specific column's first value. I was considering something like this: (df['colname'].iloc[0]) but now I am getting confused when {input} comes also into a play. So instead of a 'df' mention above should be {input}. Perhaps there is a better alternative to python .iloc? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Hopefully this addition makes it more clear. I am applying REGENIE software in a snakemake rule.

rule convert_file:
input:sumstats/{prefix}.txt.gz
output: sumstats/{prefix}.sumstats.gz
shell: 'munge_sumstats.py --chunksize 50000 --sumstats {input} --N HERE SHOULD BE {input}['colname'].iloc[0] --out {output}'

So I am not sure how to take first column value for a specific column of an input file while applying it in snakemake rule shell part.

Comment: could you provide more informations, so we can reproduce your problem and try to solve it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If df is a DataFrame, your code looks OK: it will indeed give you the first element of the column colname. Can you give a toy example if the input?

Comment: Thanks for all the previous attempts :) I have now added extra info to my question above.

Comment: Let me know if it is not clear enough what I would like to do.